# Pulling a single random String from an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

To begin, I am a very beginner in Java. I have looked at many different posts regarding similar problems but still could not seem to solve my problem.

```
String[] names = {"elephant, tiger, monkey, baboon, barbeque, giraffe,  simple, zebra, porcupine, aardvark"};
    Random rand = new Random();
    name  = names[rand.nextInt(names.length)];
    return name;
```

From this snippet of code I am trying to have Java select a single word from the string array, such as just selecting the word "Tiger". This is for a Hangman game and this is trying to select the word that the user is trying to solve. Yes, this *is* for a school assignment so teaching and not just giving code would be GREATLY appreciated.

The main problem I am running into is that when the code is going to grab the word that I want to use, it is selecting the entire String array and is trying to have the user solve the entire thing, when I just want one word from it.

If more code is needed I can supply it, just remember I am a very very beginner in programming so the code is not very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you are initializing your string array:

```
String[] names = {"elephant, tiger, monkey, baboon, barbeque, giraffe, simple, zebra, porcupine, aardvark"}
```

This is a string array with one string that is "elephant, tiger,...

You want to do this:

```
String[] names = {"elephant", "tiger", "monkey"...
```

Notice the extra quotation marks.

Comment: Awesome thank you! feel kind of silly that I didnt realize that was the issue with it initially. thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] names = {"elephant", "tiger", "monkey", "baboon", "barbeque",
                  "giraffe", "simple", "zebra", "porcupine", "aardvark"};
```

Use this, hope you understood why. You have assigned the whole thing as a single element before.

Answer (score -1):

Your array as of right now is one long string. If you were to call `names[0]`, you would get `elephant, tiger, monkey, baboon, barbeque, giraffe, simple, zebra, porcupine, aardvark` back.

You need to initialize your array with individual strings such as `elephant`, `tiger`, `monkey`, etc.